# How to replace placeholder in string with input fields and values provided in object

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, reactjs, react-native

I have string with placeholders in it. and want to replace those placeholders with input fields.

Initially when page is loaded string will be shown with input fields at place of placeholders and with values provided in object. Once user changes any input field it will be validated against given regex using onChange event.

`"Ensure that backup is greater than {maxCount} days old"`

```
{
"maxCount": {"value":"202","type":"text","regex":"^[0-9]"}
}
```

Final output on page need to be have maxCount replaced with input field and value for will be from object. string may have multiple placeholders

Following is what i have tried but issue is with placeholder values

```
let gaps = [];
    let last = '';
    let title = "Ensure that backup is greater than {maxCount} days old"
    
    const addGapsField = (row) =>{
        let text = title.split(/\{.*?\}/g)
        text.forEach((part, i) => {
          gaps.push(row.Parameters[Object.keys(row.Parameters)[0]].parameterValue)
        })
        last = text.pop()
        return text
    }

const arr = addGapsField(row)//row/Parameters contains obj to replace
<div id="app">
                    <span>
                    {
                        arr.map((part, key) =>{
                            return(
                            <>
                            {part}
                            <input key={key} className="form-control d-inline" style={{width:'45px'}} type={'text'} name={'name'} value = {gaps[key]} />
                            </>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                    </span>
                    <span>{last}</span>
                </div>
```

Comment: What? I am confused. What is an example of the result you need? It will help others understand your problem if you update your question to include your attempt at this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing the props on the input tag.

This is a PLACEHOLDER:
[image]

This is a filled VALUE in the input:
[image]

So your object should populate the placeholder prop, not the value. Your 'value' prop will be changed on the onChange callback.

```
 <input {...yourOtherProps} placeholder = {gaps[key]} />
```